# How do I reduce the file size of Windows 10 Game Bar recordings?

Tags: windows-10, screen-recorder

I use Windows Game Bar to record my screen (and not necessarily for Games). The size of the file that comes out, however, is sometimes outrageous. A 5 min recording takes up about 200 MB! Recently, I recorded a one and a half online lecture and the file size was about 8 GB; it reduced to 3.2 GB after compressing!

*How do I reduce the file size? Video quality settings under "Game Bar Settings" in Windows 10 is set to 30fps and "Standard" (Standard and High quality are the only two options).*

Comment: *How do I reduce the file size?* - Reduce the framerate (if possible)
or reduce your screen resolution.

Comment: There is no info about this, but I think it uses lossless H.264 codec, it's big by nature. It will be great if exists an option to directly use lossy compression.

Comment: It's lossy; I can tell just by looking at it that it's clearly not at the same quality as the original game segment. And high-quality video files at high resolutions simply do take up a lot of space. That's just an unfortunate reality of video and always has been. Even merely decent-looking encodings of 480p anime episodes, in the 200x's, were a couple hundred megs for 22 minutes. This modern encoding of a blu-ray anime I have is 1.5+ GB per 24 minute episode. You can only make these smaller by further reducing the quality by re-encoding, compounding the detail loss.

Answer (score 9):

I used FFMPEG and used the following command:

> d:\FFmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i "issue12.mp4" "issue12-1.mp4"

With this, there is a quality loss, but file size dropped from 68MB to 2MB for a 2 minute video.

Comment: reduced 500mb to 10mb for me

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide an explanation as to why, but here is a technique that worked for me.

Get any video editing app, and *trim a few seconds off the start or end*.
I suppose this edit causes the app to change the formatting of the video, but either way, you should have a video that is not abnormally large.

Comment: Can you give a step by step guide how to do this in VLC?

Comment: The video editor in question must be re-encoding the entire clip with its own, lossy encoding. Generally, for quality, you want to avoid encoding lossily twice, but as long as it looks acceptable, it does satisfy the request. I don't think VLC can do editing.

Answer (score -2):

See, there are settings in the gamebar which change the size of the file. Set it to Standard instead of high and done. The file will be big ofc, and that is because its recording your screen resolution.
Change the screen resolution and your file size will change automatically too.
But incase you want even more compresseed file, just pass the file through a video editor and adjust the bitrate to the lowest it can go to. Done.